# Accessing a Windows driver from Python

Tags: python, windows, driver

How do I interface with a Windows driver from Python (e.g. send an ioctl)?

On Linux it's easy as I just open the device as a file but I have no idea how to do this on Windows.

Any help would be great! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are couples library you may want to explore for

- [win32 for python](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/)
- [WMI for python](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/WMI/) with [Tutorial](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/wmi/tutorial.html)

You may need to explore the Windows WMI classes from the Huge [MSDN Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394572%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)